# Check the list of revoked certificates via proxy using HttpClient on the .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, certificate

Our application runs on Windows 10 in a closed network and all communication with the external environment is carried out through a proxy. The proxy is only used by installing it in [HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.8.1).

**We don't want to use a proxy by installing it in the system environment.**

When sending requests to the server (using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8.1)) in an external environment, we want to check the server certificate, **as well as the list of revoked certificates**.

If [ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.checkcertificaterevocationlist?view=netframework-4.8.1) set to **true**; In this case, the verification of the list of revoked certificates is checked **directly by the link that is specified in the CRL**.

It looks like .net delegates the verification of the list of revoked certificates to the operating system.

Is it possible that the list of revoked certificates is also checked through a proxy, but without specifying a proxy in the system environment?

UPD:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseProxy = true };

httpClientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy("proxy");

httpClientHandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "uri");

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
string responseJsonData = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Please show relevant code. Have you tried setting `HttpClientHandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList` as `ServicePointManager` is deprecated?

Comment: @Charlieface, I added the code. And yes, I tried to do as you wrote. The result is the same.

Comment: One option could be to verify the certificates yourself within `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that the list of revoked certificates is also checked through a proxy, but without specifying a proxy in the system environment?

No.  As you already surmised, the file download isn't even done by .NET (at least on Windows), it's done by the OS as a black-box detail of either [CertGetCertificateChain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain) or [CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certverifycertificatechainpolicy) (I forget which, but they get called together).